# Elixir Mix release - How can I copy extra files into the tarball of Phoenix app?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I wrote the following mix.exs to release my Phoenix application as a tar ball, referring to the “Steps” section of the Mix.Tasks.Release [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html#module-steps).

```
defmodule MyApp.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      apps_path: "apps",
      apps: [:shared, :admin, :shop],
      version: "0.1.0",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() in [:qa, :prod],
      deps: deps(),
      releases: [
        my_app: [
          applications: [
            admin: :permanent,
            shop: :permanent
          ],
          steps: [:assemble, &copy_extra_files/1, :tar]
        ]
      ],
      default_release: :my_app
    ]
  end

  defp copy_extra_files(release) do
    File.cp_r("apps/shared/priv/repo/seeds", release.path <> "/seeds")
    release
  end

  defp deps do
    []
  end
end
```

When I run `MIX_ENV=qa mix release my_app`, it created a `seeds` directory under `_build/qa/rel/my_app`, but when I extract the generated tar ball, it does not contain the `seeds` directory.

How can I rewrite the `mix.exs` in order to insert this directory into the tar ball?

Elixir version is 1.11.3.

Note: [The same question](https://elixirforum.com/t/mix-release-how-can-i-copy-extra-files-into-tar-ball/36921) has been posted on the Elixir Forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to copy anything manually since elixir does this for you automatically, if you take a look in your `my_app/lib/my_app-0.1.0/priv`, there you have all the files you had in your priv folder.

Now in order to access those resources painless without hardcoding the path you can use [`priv_dir\1`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#priv_dir-1):

```
:code.priv_dir(:my_app)
```

This is applicable not only for your application, for example if you want your phoenix static resources, you can find them in phoenix priv folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One note. To use it in Elixir code, we need to write something like `List.to_string(:code.priv_dir(:shared))`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.11.3/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/release.ex#L1130-L1133) for `mix.release`, it appears to only select from specific directories when compiling the release.

If you copy `seeds` into `#{release.path}/releases/#{release.version}`, it will be included.

```elixir
defp copy_extra_files(release) do
  File.cp_r(
    "apps/shared/priv/repo/seeds",
    "#{release.path}/releases/#{release.version}/seeds"
  )

  release
end
```

Comment: It's obvious from Daniel's answer that this is the wrong approach. But it could possibly be useful for copying files that are not in the `priv/` directory, so I'll leave it for now.